# Get a string of an object list by property

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I was wondering the best way to get the string of a list made of object elements, then select a property to create the string. Something like the following:

```
items = []
for element in self.items:
    items.append(element.description)
items_str = ",".join(items)
```

Where self.items is an object of a class <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.collections.InstrumentedList'> and the definition includes code and description properties:

```
class ItemsByCategory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Items_by_category'
    category = db.Column(db.String(3), primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

Many Thanks

Comment: I'm unsure on "what the best way to get the string mean", but if you want to combine the code into a single line. You can do so using python list comprehension like below, `items_str = ",".join(element.description for element in self.items)`

Comment: Thanks @Kite, I was thinking if I can use map like the following: `map(self.items, lambda x: ",".join(x.description))`, but getting error `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable` when passing self.items as parameter of type <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.collections.InstrumentedList'>.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following example can help you！

```
class Count(object):
        def __init__(self, mymin, mymax):
            self.mymin = mymin
            self.mymax = mymax
            self.current = None
    
        def __getattr__(self, item):
            self.__dict__[item] = 0
            return 0
    
        def __getattribute__(self, item):
            if item.startswith('cur'):
                raise AttributeError
            return object.__getattribute__(self, item)
            # or you can use ---return super().__getattribute__(item)
            # note this class subclass object
    
    
    obj1 = Count(1, 10)
    print(obj1.mymin)
    print(obj1.mymax)
    print(obj1.current)
    
    # 1
    # 10
    # 0
```